# change color of modal blocker background depending on id (not bootstrap or jquery ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

This has to be really simple but I can't figure it out -

I am using this plugin https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js for modal pop-ups on my site & I'd like to have a different color blocker background on each.

I can't seem to target the blocker's css to change its color dynamically. When I click to open the modal, the blocker div and classes appear:

```
<div class="jquery-modal blocker current">
::before
<div id="id1" class="modal" style="display: inline-block;">
</div>
</div>
```

From what I can gather, this is the relevant js:

```
block: function () {
                this.$elm.trigger(o.modal.BEFORE_BLOCK, [this._ctx()]),
                    this.$body.css({ position: "relative", overflow: "hidden", height: "100%" }),
                    (this.$blocker = o('<div class="' + this.options.blockerClass + ' blocker current"></div>').appendTo(this.$body)),
                    n(),
                    this.options.doFade && this.$blocker.css("opacity", 0).animate({ opacity: 1 }, this.options.fadeDuration),
                    this.$elm.trigger(o.modal.BLOCK, [this._ctx()]);
            },
            unblock: function (t) {
                !t && this.options.doFade
                    ? this.$blocker.fadeOut(this.options.fadeDuration, this.unblock.bind(this, !0))
                    : (this.$blocker.children().appendTo(this.$body), this.$blocker.remove(), (this.$blocker = null), n(), o.modal.isActive() || this.$body.css({ position: "", overflow: "", height: "" }));
            },
```

and this bit too, I guess:

```
(o.modal.getCurrent = l),
(o.modal.defaults = {
    closeExisting: !0,
    escapeClose: !0,
    clickClose: !0,
    closeText: "&#10005;",
    closeClass: "",
    modalClass: "modal",
    blockerClass: "jquery-modal",
    spinnerHtml: '<div class="rect1"></div><div class="rect2"></div><div class="rect3"></div><div class="rect4"></div>',
    showSpinner: !0,
    showClose: !0,
    fadeDuration: null,
    fadeDelay: 1,
}),
```

I've tried targeting 'jquery-modal' and changing the background-color with a script at the end of my html document:

```
$('a[data-modal]').click(function(event) {
  $(this).modal();
  $('.jquery-modal').css('background-color, red');
  return false;
});
```

I've tried the same with '.blocker' and '.jquery-modal.blocker.current'. I've also tried to create a new additional class to sit on top of the blocker but it seems clunky and unnecessary.

I basically don't know how to target the active blocker so I can change the color depending on the id of the modal that's been opened.

Comment: You tried .modal {background:color;}

Comment: it's not the modal background color I'm trying to change, it's the div that covers the rest of the page behind it - usually black or white. I tried it anyway and it didn't do anything.